# Custom boost python module with built in mpi?

Tags: c++, python, boost, mpi

Is it possible, in principle, to use the boost python library to create a custom python module in C++ that has MPI functionality? So I wonder if I can include MPI functionality in some of the library's functions, and then create a python script like this:

```
import myModule

A = myModule.myClass()

A.doSomething()
```

where doSomething() is a function with some opportunity for parallelisation. I'd then do

```
mpirun -np [NUM_PROCS] python my_script.py [OPTIONS]
```

and get parallel functionality. If this is possible, how would I go about it? I mean obviously I'd need to include some MPI library in my module's source, but would I need to do something in the python script to ensure that it ran in parallel? Would I have to battle with the GIL? There doesn't seem to be much documentation on this, so I'm a bit clueless as to how I'd go about it. Alternatively, if I've missed some documentation somewhere a URL would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this rather than say use [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/)?

Comment: Well I initially had a library written in python, but it was extremely slow. Now it's compiled in C++ it's a lot faster, but I've extended it (i.e. added functions with more numerical manipulation) to the point where it's taking quite a while to run again. Doing the basic calculations take a few hours, but with the extensions to the code it's taking the better half of a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation it is possible to do this. The library needs to be compiled with mpicxx, and the python script that calls it will need to initialize the mpi environment. For example, I used mpi4py to do MPI.COMM_WORLD. The library functions are then called by all processes, and the function can contain code to control the flow of data between processes.